# Reason for icons (icon fonts) always in ::before pseudo-selector

Tags: css, css-selectors, icons, glyphicons

**Is there a reason, so many icon-Libraries (Glyhpicon, Font Awesome, Antd icons,…) put their icon in the `::before–pseudo` selector?** (rather than in the tag directly?)

```
i::before {
    content: '\E60A';
    ...
}
```

Comment: Because that makes it trivial to switch a specific icon for a different character through the whole site via CSS; because they are mostly rather “decoration” than actual content; ...

Comment: And because you can't put a `content` in an element itself. This is actually a restriction of CSS.

Comment: @MrLister Ah! [true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19771373/444255), never thought about that one. – Sounds like the accepted to be answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a reason, so many icon-Libraries (Glyhpicon, Font Awesome, Antd icons,…) put their icon in the ::before–pseudo selector?

That method has several advantages ...

- makes it trivial to switch a specific icon for a different character throughout the whole site via CSS
- such icons are mostly used rather as “decoration” than actual content (so this touches on the issue of accessibility as well)
- you can't insert `content` in an actual element itself, that is reserved for pseudo elements (thanks @Mr Lister for this one)